# Do I need arcgis engine license in order to develop arcgis engine applications?

Tags: licensing, arcgis

I'm in process of learning ArcGIS development. To be honest, I'm hugely confused about:

1) The differences between **ArcObjects** and **ArcGIS Engine**

2) and mostly , about **licensing** .

Right now , I'm trying to follow this [walk-through](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/7bd52ed1-18ae-4aa7-8cde-e9eaed9537fe.htm)  but every time I try to  add a control from ArcGIS Engine controls, Visual Studio throws an error complaining that, the control is not licensed .

Do I need ArcGIS Engine license in order to develop ArcGIS Engine applications, or what?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about licensing. [Where can I ask about Software Licenses/Licensing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165980/where-can-i-ask-about-software-licenses-licensing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. ArcObjects is the ArcGIS API that is behind ArcGIS Desktop (off-the-shelf GIS software), ArcGIS Engine (GIS components for building your own software), and ArcGIS Server (complete server GIS). Building standalone apps with ArcGIS Engine is one thing you can do with the ArcObjects API.
2. To develop ArcObjects code, including ArcGIS Engine applications, you need the ArcObjects SDK, previously known as the ArcGIS Engine Developer Kit. To get the SDK, you have to subscribe to the [Esri Developer Network](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/edn), which costs money. If you don't have the SDK, you will get Visual Studio errors like the kind you describe.

Having said all of that, if you're just now learning ArcGIS development, you're better off using the ArcGIS Runtime SDKs. They're more modern and faster than ArcGIS Engine, they're easier to use, and they're available at no cost. Since you're using Visual Studio, you should use the [ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/).